# glibc-2.14 make error: encounter shlib.lds syntax error

Tags: makefile, glibc

OS is RHEL6.  I don't have root permissions.  The OS has glibc-2.12, and I'm trying to upgrade it to glibc-2.14.

`configure` runs fine.  However, when I run `make`, I get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld:/<GLIBC INSTALL DIR>/build/shlib.lds:47: syntax error
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/<GLIBC INSTALL DIR>/build/libc.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/<GLIBC INSTALL DIR>/elf'
make[1]: *** [elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/<GLIBC INSTALL DIR>'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have no idea how to fix this error, and tried googling but haven't found any solutions.  Any clues?

Comment: Would you please add the relevant part of `shlib.lds` (around line 47) to your question? Thanks.